# Facebook JS Batch Request Returns Null

Tags: javascript, facebook

This has puzzled me for a couple of days.  I'm trying to use Facebook's Javascript SDK to write a batch request, but it has always returned [null].  Am I missing something?  Thanks in advance.

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', {
        batch: [
            {method: 'GET', relative_url: 'me', omit_response_on_success: 'false'},
            {method: 'GET', name: 'get-friends', relative_url: 'me/friends', omit_response_on_success: 'false'} 
        ]
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the single quotes around `omit_response_on_success: 'false'` works for me:

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', {
    batch: [
        {method: 'GET', relative_url: 'me', omit_response_on_success: false},
        {method: 'GET', name: 'get-friends', relative_url: 'me/friends', omit_response_on_success: false}
    ]
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```